# OkHttpClient get response body

Tags: java, request, response, http-status-code-403, okhttp

I want get body response, but get error 403, although the page opens in webview and browser. My code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(url)
                            .build();

                    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Error load URL", e.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
                        {
                            if (response.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                htmlPage = response.body().string();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //I find myself here.
                                Log.e("Error load URL", "Response error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

> url =
>   "http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/cart.workflow:ShowCart?shopping-menu-selected-line=cart&menu-id=currentcart"

response from server:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden,
>   url=http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/cart.workflow:ShowCart?shopping-menu-selected-line=cart&menu-id=currentcart}

In browser everything is good. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your client has authorized or authenticated to the web service.
This can happen if the security is enabled on the web service that you are calling try to authenticate / authorize yourself to the web service and then start consuming it.

Answer (score 1):

Extension to Kiran, 403 represents an authorization issue. Not an authentication issue. It's very possible that in browser authentication and authorization is managed using a cookie which may not be handled in your code.